# How do I get a Captcha off a website and display it in a picturebox using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, captcha, picturebox

In Visual Basic .NET is there a way to access a website/signup page and then get the Captcha and load it into a picturebox? How would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I can't tell if you are looking for a captcha plug-in or use a plug-in from another site. If you're looking for a plugin, try [Recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

**UPDATE**

Trying to pull a the captcha image off of a site could be done in two ways, but it the captcha rotation were done correctly, it would no do you any good to be able to pull it off.

One way would be to just right-click on the image and reference that URL in your code. However, as stated previously, this would not be that reliable. The service that generates the image would rotate, and the image URL would be different on every refresh. In other words, the copied URL would only be good for the one time you copied/captured it via right-click or whatever. If the URL did not rotate, then that would be a security issue for the site which is why the image source is different on each refresh.

Another way would be to make a direct request to the page, scrape the content for the captcha image's source, and pull the source from the parsed content. The code for this would be fairly specific per page, and, with my limited knowledge, I can't think of a way to make a generic application to do so.

I don't know why you would want to do what you are wanting to do, unless this is a homework assignment, or you are up to no good.

Comment: I mean like downloading the captcha off another website to display in my picturebox, like from Google or Yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the captcha service the website uses.
If the site uses reCAPTCHA, you would probably need to look for the image tag that has id "recaptcha_challenge_image" and display that image tag in a web browser control.
Here is the demo page I found: http://www.google.com/recaptcha/demo/. If the captcha itself is in a frame (or iframe), you will need to check the code in the frame itself.